# please guide me what is the meaning of star in the code

Tags: pandas, dataframe

please guide what is the meaning of star in the code

```
range(*window_range)
```

thank you

I do not know at all about this code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) mean in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-do-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-mean-in-a-function-call)

Answer (score 1):

A star in the context of a function call like this will unpack the iterable after the star and give it to the function as separate positional arguments.

So in this case if window_range wera a tuple giving the window range, eg `(0, 10)` this would call `range(0,10)`

See [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/tuple_unpack.html) for more detail.